# adjustbox missing endgroup inserted. How to fit longtable to page width?

Tags: tables, pgfplots, longtable, landscape, adjustbox

I am working on my thesis. The appendix contains 2 large tables that span multiple pages. These tables are wider than the page height in landscape mode. When using the `\begin{adjustbox}{width = 1\textheight}` it produces multiple errors:

1. `Missing \endgroup inserted`...
2. `Missing } inserted`
3. `Package graphixs Error: Division by 0`
4. `Argument of \LT@max has an extra }`
5. `Paragraph ended before \LT@max`

Among others. The document compiles normally if the `\begin{adjustbox}` / `\end{adjustbox}` is  commented out. The .csv files are found in [my github repo for my thesis](https://github.com/FranciscoMenendez/quinua_repo/blob/master/Anexo3_genotipos.csv). The code used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
```

[...]

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textheight}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type, 
    col sep=comma,
    outfile=prueba.tex,
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    every head row/.append style={after row={
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{13}{c}{{\bfseries  -- continua de la pagina anterior}}\\\hline
        Accesion& Fecha& Pais& Departamento& Provincia& Distrito& Localidad& Altitud (m)& Latitud& Longitud& Fuente& Status& Mat. Viv. Col.\\\hline
        \endhead},
    before row={\hline}}        
    ]{apendice/pasaporte.csv}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
```

[...]

```
\end{document}
```

The packages loaded are:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{norte}{HTML}{1B9E77}
\definecolor{centro}{HTML}{E7298A}
\definecolor{sur}{HTML}{666666}
\usepackage[round, comma, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english, spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{imagenes/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg, .jpeg}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{pgf}    
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
input-symbols = {()},
group-digits  = false,
explicit-sign
}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage,lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

## Data:

```
\begin {longtable}{ccccccccccccccc}%
\hline Accesion&KAAT007&QCA14&QGAA001&QGA17&KGA16&QAAT071&QAAT084&QAAT081&KGA20&KCAA011&QAAT050&QGA028&QAAT012&Provincia\\\hline \endfirsthead \multicolumn {15}{c}{{\bfseries -- continua de la pagina anterior}}\\\hline Accesión& KAAT007& QCA14& QGAA001& QGA17& KGA16& QAAT071& QAAT084& QAAT081& KGA20& KCAA011& QAAT050& QGA028& QAAT012& Provincia\\\hline \endhead %
 1&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&SUCRE\\%
      2&225/225&205/205&NA&198/202&198/198&NA&176/176&206/206&214/224&NA&250/250&194/194&204/204&SUCRE\\%
3&225/291&NA&NA&198/198&198/198&164/164&170/170&206/206&212/220&235/235&247/247&222/222&204/204&SUCRE\\%
 5&315/315&203/207&NA&NA&NA&NA&170/170&206/206&NA&NA&NA&220/220&198/198&SUCRE\\%
6&255/255&203/207&143/206&NA&200/200&179/179&170/170&206/206&190/196&NA&223/223&220/220&198/198&SUCRE\\%
7&261/276&205/207&200/206&194/200&194/194&179/179&176/176&206/209&206/214&247/247&217/220&196/196&222/222&SUCRE\\%
8&NA&NA&206/236&194/202&200/200&NA&164/164&206/206&NA&NA&NA&202/214&189/231&SUCRE\\%
9&294/294&NA&NA&NA&196/198&179/179&167/167&206/206&206/214&NA&217/241&198/198&201/201&SUCRE\\%
10&342/342&207/207&245/266&196/196&NA&NA&173/173&206/206&190/196&NA&223/223&224/224&198/198&HUAMANGA\\%
13&225/225&205/209&NA&NA&196/200&164/164&179/194&206/209&214/222&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUAMANGA\\%
14&222/222&NA&NA&196/200&196/196&164/164&179/179&209/209&216/224&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUAMANGA\\%
15&NA&205/207&NA&180/196&200/200&173/173&173/173&206/206&190/194&241/241&220/220&224/224&225/225&HUAMANGA\\%
 16&228/228&207/211&209/209&182/200&200/200&164/164&164/164&206/206&214/222&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUANCASANCOS\\%
 \end {longtable}%
```

Comment: Rather than `adjustbox`, can't you use a different font size for the tabular material?

Comment: do not put longtable in a center environment or adjustbox if you must drag it out full width (which almost never makes a table easier to read) see the example at the start of section 5 of the longtable manual.

Comment: @jon; using pgfplotstable should i just add `\tiny` (or similar) to the  pgfplotstabletypeset option? I just tried it and didn't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; the table width exceeds the page width.  Fortunately these tables are presented as appendices.  They are kind of mandatory in the mind of the revisors.

Comment: It is impossible to suggest a reformatting if you do not show an example but never put a longtable in center or adjustbox, neither will do anything useful for a longtable. You can use a smaller font, or use narrower columns with linebreaking within the column, or any one of a number of ways to affect the table width

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added a link to the data. https://github.com/FranciscoMenendez/quinua_repo/blob/master/pasaporte.csv

Comment: the site works best if you make a small self contained example and add it to the question. The question is archived forever but won't make sense if the code in that link changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier for people to help if you post a complete document, as below, that shows the problem rather than disconnected fragments, but anyway, it fits on the page if you reduce the font size, and steal a bit of the bottom margin.

[image]
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage{lscape,longtable}
    \begin{document}

```
\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\setlength\LTleft{-70pt}
\begin {longtable}{ccccccccccccccc}%
\hline Accesion&KAAT007&QCA14&QGAA001&QGA17&KGA16&QAAT071&QAAT084&QAAT081&KGA20&KCAA011&QAAT050&QGA028&QAAT012&Provincia\\\hline \endfirsthead \multicolumn {15}{c}{{\bfseries -- continua de la pagina anterior}}\\\hline Accesión& KAAT007& QCA14& QGAA001& QGA17& KGA16& QAAT071& QAAT084& QAAT081& KGA20& KCAA011& QAAT050& QGA028& QAAT012& Provincia\\\hline \endhead %
 1&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&NA&SUCRE\\%
      2&225/225&205/205&NA&198/202&198/198&NA&176/176&206/206&214/224&NA&250/250&194/194&204/204&SUCRE\\%
3&225/291&NA&NA&198/198&198/198&164/164&170/170&206/206&212/220&235/235&247/247&222/222&204/204&SUCRE\\%
 5&315/315&203/207&NA&NA&NA&NA&170/170&206/206&NA&NA&NA&220/220&198/198&SUCRE\\%
6&255/255&203/207&143/206&NA&200/200&179/179&170/170&206/206&190/196&NA&223/223&220/220&198/198&SUCRE\\%
7&261/276&205/207&200/206&194/200&194/194&179/179&176/176&206/209&206/214&247/247&217/220&196/196&222/222&SUCRE\\%
8&NA&NA&206/236&194/202&200/200&NA&164/164&206/206&NA&NA&NA&202/214&189/231&SUCRE\\%
9&294/294&NA&NA&NA&196/198&179/179&167/167&206/206&206/214&NA&217/241&198/198&201/201&SUCRE\\%
10&342/342&207/207&245/266&196/196&NA&NA&173/173&206/206&190/196&NA&223/223&224/224&198/198&HUAMANGA\\%
13&225/225&205/209&NA&NA&196/200&164/164&179/194&206/209&214/222&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUAMANGA\\%
14&222/222&NA&NA&196/200&196/196&164/164&179/179&209/209&216/224&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUAMANGA\\%
15&NA&205/207&NA&180/196&200/200&173/173&173/173&206/206&190/194&241/241&220/220&224/224&225/225&HUAMANGA\\%
 16&228/228&207/211&209/209&182/200&200/200&164/164&164/164&206/206&214/222&235/235&247/247&224/224&207/207&HUANCASANCOS\\%
 \end {longtable}
 \end{landscape}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly, however, the table lies on top of the page number if using `pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: @Panchito yes sure the `\setlength\LTleft{-70pt}` is only really available if you have space at the bottom. If you have space at the top just move it down less, or if you have header and footer then you have to use a smaller font size like `\tiny` or consider using `\pagestyle{empty}`  in that appendix to leave room or....

Comment: I removed the numbering with `pagestyle{empty}`. Appreciated good sir!